# awk : how to read input records

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I want to read values from `input1.txt`. Based on the read values, I will take action on `input2.xml`
I am invoking my awk script as ,

```
$bash: awk -f myAwk.awk input1.txt input2.xml

$bash: cat myAwk.awk
{
print $0;
}

/<record / { i=1 }
i { a[i++]=$0 }
/<\/record>/ {
    if (found) {
       //Do some action
    }
    i=0;
    found=0
}
/SEARCH { found=1 }

$bash: cat input1.txt
SEARCH
DONTSEARCH
```

Problem is

1: When I invoke my `awk` script, it is priting values from `input2.xml` on standard output.

2: How to loop through each value from `input1.txt` and place that in `SEARCH`?

Comment: It would be useful to see an example of your inputs and desired output, so we can offer you better advice.

Comment: Please see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to

- read the first file into memory, then
- process a second file,

the canonical construct within awk is along the lines of

```
FNR=NR {
  # read stuff from the first file, perhaps store it in an array.
  next;
}

{
  # read the second file, do things to it.
}
```

The variable `NR` is the current number of records (lines) that awk has processed, and `FNR` is the current number of records that have been processed *in the current file*. They are only equal while you're inside the first file.

Your script is printing the content of `input2.xml` because the very first statement in your script tells it to do exactly that -- `print $0`. Which can be shortened to just `print`.  Or the entire bracketed statement could be replaced with a `1`.

You haven't included sample data or expected output in your question, so I can only guess what you're *really* trying to achieve here.  (In particular, there's no explanation of what you're trying to do with the `a` and `i` variables.)  Perhaps you want something more along the lines of this:

```
# Set a semaphore for later use, only if "SEARCH" is in the first file.
NR==FNR && /^SEARCH/ {
  found=1
}
# Also, store everything from the first file in an array.
NR==FNR {
  array[NR]=$0
  next
}

/<record / {
  # Do something, perhaps using array[]
  if (found) {
    # Do something else only if we found SEARCH in the first file.
  }
}
```

Comment: It would probably help if you showed the *full* canonical invocation including the program name, and the quotes around the code and how to specify two input files, otherwise inexperienced readers (who maybe need your sound advice) might get stuck with how to actually use it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, it might -- though in this answer I elected to keep things simple and included only the code within the awk script because the question clearly demonstrates that the OP already understands how to compose an awk script and then invoke awk with multiple input files. Do you think inexperienced readers would jump to this answer before reading the question?

Comment: I just remember when I started out and could never get anything to work, and had to go back to people and ask why and they'd say *"Oh, you need to include such and such header files"*, and gave me a list of seven files they hadn't mentioned, and I'd try again and have to go back and they'd say *"Oh, did you link with such and such libraries"*? And I'd be thinking *"No, you didn't mention them"*. Still it didn't work, and then I'd find out I needed such and such compiler switches and frameworks. Sometimes I think we don't help beginners enough and we assume they know everything we know.

Answer (score 2):

For that specific case, you need to change the line to:

```
NR==FNR && /SEARCH/ { found=1 }
```

But perhaps, depending on your needs, an easier way to do it would simply be:

```
awk -f myAwk.awk found=1 input2.xml
```

That is, you can set the variables on the command line outside of the script.  Then you don't need the /SEARCH/ line at all...

Answer (score 0):

## Original:

This is something that I thought that I would never say:

I would recommend grep in this scenario, and please hear me out before deciding TLDR.

I recommend this for the sole reason that grep will exit with boolean logic and awk does not. ( I have an out of date version of awk since I am testing this on my work Mac, so this may have changed in recent years. )

```
$ grep "zzz" test && echo true || false
$ awk "zzz" test && echo true || false
true
$
```

You can set up a simple for loop that would compare the files and write (or do something esle if you want)

```
$ for i in $(cat file1); do grep "$i" file2 || echo "$i" >> file2; done
grep: file2: No such file or directory
158
085
596
82
Worst012345678910Best
82
Worst012345678910Best
254
Worst012345678910Best
Worst012345678910Best
399
```

The above output was duplicate entries with the exception of the first line (obviously)

```
$ cat file2
1
katyperry
KATY
PERRY
(@katyperry)
Followings
158
Followers
82
085
596
Rating
Worst012345678910Best
justinbieber
Justin
Bieber
(@justinbieber)
254
399
74
748
878
taylorswift13
Taylor
Swift
(@taylorswift13)
245
70
529
992
```

Here is the Bash version that this was test in.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$
```

## Edit:

A practical example of this would be writing a script that will only edit system files once no matter how many times the script is run:

```
grep NOZEROCONF /etc/sysconfig/network 2> /dev/null || echo "NOZEROCONF=yes" >> /etc/sysconfig/network
```

On CentOS and RHEL systems the above line could be run a ton of times and the file would only be written once.

Another thing that could be done is comparing the output of one command to the output of another or in this case a directory using grep as a logic switch:

```
for i in /dev/sd[^ab]*; 
do 
    ( pvs | grep -q "$i" ) && 
    echo "$i" configured || ( 
        code block to configure drive
done;
```

Comment: You can easily instruct Awk to return an exit code, but you need to do it yourself.  `awk '/zzz/ { found=1; print } END { exit 1-found }' file`

Comment: I did not know that... but in this scenario it just seems like more work.

Comment: Oh, definitely; I just reacted on your opening statement's assertion that Awk "does not" do this. Awk is a fairly general-purpose language and so it would be extremely unwise if its creators had hard-coded a failure exit code for a successful script which however did not execute some particular branch (which one, anyway? How would you formalize any sane behavior for this?)

Comment: Running another grep on the second file for each line in the first file seems like a good idea to you? Seems to me that it would be far preferable, if you have to files, to read just two files. Also, there's nothing wrong with OSX's awk. It's just not GNU. Code that you write for awk in OSX is likely to work in other awks.

Comment: The subshell (the parentheses) are not necessary for the pipeline `pvs | grep -q "$i"` (though I would definitely quote the variable, and generally any variable containing a file name).

Comment: I would say all of these, making an edit or executing some code based on a comparison between two outputs using a search key. Unless there was going to be some serious awk voodoo going on in the creator's myAwk.awk.

Comment: Damn it! You're right I pulled that from one of my first scripts.